# Can't create DOMPoint in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to create a DOMPoint myself in Typescript, and nothing seems to be working.

I've tried both the constructor and the `DOMPoint.fromPoint` method, and neither work. When I try and log my results, all I get is a default initialized structure.

Weirdly enough, `createSVGPoint` seems to work, as does just creating a point in the Chrome console. But, when I try and use it in Typescript code, it simply does not work.

I feel like I'm going insane because I can't find anything else about this problem, and it should be so simple.

Comment: hello friend, first we need to distinguish the problem from being either (A: a javascript issue at runtime) or (B: a typescript problem at compile time) — are the errors you are experiencing happening in the web browser, or are they coming from the typescript compiler?

Comment: in a javascript console, i find that both of these work (A: `new DOMPoint(1, 2, 3, 4)`) and also (B: `DOMPoint.fromPoint({x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, w: 4})`)

Comment: i will also note that in a typescript project of mine, the above examples are working for me -- ensure that your `tsconfig.json` has the following "compilerOptions": { `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` }

Comment: It turns out that I was initializing the points with `DOMRect.left` etc. attributes, which apparently are also broken. Upgrading to 'esnext' and adding the lib options like you said didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## Configure TypeScript "lib" to "es6"

Here is a `tsconfig.json` from one of my TypeScript projects, where I've marked the `lib` field with `// <== !IMPORTANT!` because I think it might be the relevant configuration to allow `DOMPoint` to work

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "source",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"], // <== !IMPORTANT!
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "source/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "source-old/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**Warning!** It looks like `DOMPoint` [may not be widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint#Browser_compatibility), it might not work in Edge